# How can I count the number of top level json keys in a Snowflake database variant field?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for the number 2 here...  array_size appears to work on a variant list but is not doing so well on this json.  Is there a clever way to do this?  I don't know/probably can't trust the structure will only go this deep, and am hoping to use this as just another field on a query where I'm pulling out a bunch of other values out of the json; so ideally a solution allows this as well.

```
select dict, array_size(dict)
from (select parse_json('{
  "partition": [
    "partition_col"
  ],
  "sample_weight": [
    "sample_weight"
  ]
}') as dict)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you can create a small Javascript UDF:

```
create or replace function count_keys(MYVAR variant)
returns float
language javascript
as '
    return (Object.entries(MYVAR)).length
'
;
```

To call it:

```
select count_keys(parse_json(
'{
    "partition": [
      "partition_col"
    ],
    "sample_weight": [
      "sample_weight"
    ]
  }')
)
;
```

Comment: The UDF function looks *way* better than `FLATTEN()` in your SQL code and I believe it executes significantly faster as well.

Comment: Interestingly in a test of 400K rows with JSON containing 1000 elements each, the Javascript took 17 secs and the Flatten took 3 secs on a Medium WH.

Comment: Seems you are right, I got 5 min vs 17 secs on an X-Small warehouse.  I've seen the opposite, so it might depend on your case.  But I never suspected such a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use flatten:

```
with dict as (
  select parse_json('{
    "partition": [
      "partition_col"
    ],
    "sample_weight": [
      "sample_weight"
    ]
  }') val
)
select val, count(*) 
from   dict,
       lateral flatten(input => val)
group by val
;
```

Comment: I thought this would be a solution; but I didn't want to do something like count(distinct id) then group by the 30 other columns on this record, so was hoping there was some kind of more elegant count function that would avoid the flattening.

Comment: In that case you could write a Javascript UDF that returns the count of Object.entries() in the JSON object...  That should apply only to the top-level object attributes.

Comment: @doyouevendata can you mark the solution if this solved it?

Answer (score 0):

```
select array_size(
    OBJECT_KEYS(
        parse_json('{
          "partition": [
            "partition_col"
        ],
          "sample_weight": [
            "sample_weight"
        ]
     }')
  )
) as num_of_top_lvl_keys;
```

If the object contains nested objects (e.g. objects within objects), the OBJECT_KEYS returns only the keys from the top-most level.